# Count number of twigs in a tree recursively

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

The title is pretty vague, so here's the details. I need to make a recursive function, that given the root node of a binary tree, returns the number of twigs. A twig is defined as:

- X has depth of at least 2
- X has excatly 2 children
- X and it's parent must not have a sibling

I have a boolean method that checks if a node is a twig. However, the recursive function that counts the number of twigs is difficult to make. Here's my failed attempt:

```
TWIGCOUNT(X){
if(TWIG(X) == true)
    return 1;
else if(X.left!= null)
    return TWIGCOUNT(X.left)
else if(X.right!= null)
    return TWIGCOUNT(X.right)
return 0;
```

I don't know how to properly make a recursive call to the whole left- and right-side. Right now it only checks all the branches to the left (where there are no twigs), and returns zero.

Comment: Your calls to left and right look ok, but should you call both and sum them?  Also, would it be possible for a twig to have further twigs under its children ?

Comment: so instead of returning `TWIGCOUNT(X.left)` and `TWIGCOUNT(X.right)` i should declare them as variables a and b, and return a+b instead of 0?

Comment: Also it is not possible for the given tree for a twig to have further twigs underneath.

Comment: Yes, adding them seems to be the way to get whole total. Nothing in the stated rules stops twigs from having further twigs underneath - the “ X and it's parent must not have a sibling” means X’s **immediate** children cannot be a twig, but doesn’t stop grandchildren and below.